# missing one out of the desired 3 outputs from for loop

Tags: c++, loops

from an inital input of (inval) that tells the code how many values to read for ex (2, so we read from 355 and 380)
im supposed to get ( value read: 355, value read: 380, smallest : 355) but im getting (value read: 380, smallest :355) im new to all this an have no idea where im going wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int valCount;
   int inVal;
   int smallestVal;
   int i;

   cin >> valCount;
   cin >> smallestVal;
   for (i = 1; i < valCount; ++i) {
      cin >> inVal;
      cout << "Value read: " << inVal << endl;
      if (inVal < smallestVal) {
         smallestVal = inVal;
      }
   }


 cout << "Smallest: " << smallestVal<< endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not the loop, it's the fact that you read two values before the loop begins, and do not print them.  Add "Count read" and "First value read" outputs above the loop.

Comment: `cin >> smallestVal;` is before the loop and the value is not printed  The loop executes once and the value read inside it is printed. The final result is printed. It seems you either need a special case to print the special case value read before the loop or you need to rearrange the loop so you can read all of the values in it and print them there.